# I can't click on the links because the header takes up all of my site

Tags: html

Links inside `<div>` are not clickable. and for some reason the whole site is covered with `<header>`, I couldn't figure it out. Links (`<a>`) inside `<nav>` working but `<header>` inside links not working.
how can I solve this problem?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Skyline Beach NBP', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
}

.material-symbols-sharp {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 1, 'wght' 700, 'GRAD' 200, 'opsz' 48
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.material-symbols-sharp {
  color: #dadada;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arkaplan {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 120px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1920px;
  background-color: #121212;
  z-index: -1;
}

.anasayfa {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  margin-top: 90px;
  width: 1105px;
  height: 1720px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.blok {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.lock {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #252525;
}

.kurallar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

em {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-style: normal;
  /* Removes italics */
  text-decoration: 1.5px underline #dadada;
  /* Makes underline */
}

p {
  font-family: 'Skyline Beach NBP', sans-serif;
  color: #dadada;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}

.baslik {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #dadada;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  font-family: 'Skyline Beach NBP', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #dadada;
  text-decoration: 1.5px underline #3c3c3c;
  z-index: 22;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: none!important;
  outline: none!important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="arkaplan">
      <div class="anasayfa">
        <div class="blok">
          <img class="lock" src="goruntuler/img.png">
          <p class="baslik">thehamam nedir?</p>
          <a id="kurallar" href="https://thehamam.com/kurallar" target="_blank"><span>kurallarımız</span></a>
          <p>eğer 3 kelime ile özetleyecek olursak "özgür sosyal ağ" olacaktır. genişçe tanımlarsak günümüz platformlarındaki kısıtlamaların bulunmadığı isteyen kişilerin anonim kalabileceği yegane ağ. unutmayın, thehamam verilenizi canı gibi korur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blok">
          <img class="lock" href="/" src="goruntuler/pepe.png">
          <p class="baslik">peki bu ağda ne yapılıyor?</p>
          <p>onlarca konudan birini seçip gönderi oluşturabilir, dosya yükleyebilir, ruh halinizi yansıtacak wojağınızı seçebilir ve gönderilere cevap verebilirsiniz. kurallarımız baskıcı değildir. fikirlerinizi özgürce ifade edebilirsiniz.</p>
        </div>
        <p sid="son" bu sayfanın sonu olsa gerek!></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Rendered output]

Comment: Your <header> tag looks as if it wraps around all your content. It's doing as expected. If all that content around "arkaplan" div is not part of the header why is your header class there? Maybe post some CSS so we can see what it is doing?

Comment: Can you include your CSS?

Comment: I added css code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `z-index` for `.arkaplan` to 1000:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Skyline Beach NBP', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
}

.material-symbols-sharp {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 1, 'wght' 700, 'GRAD' 200, 'opsz' 48
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.material-symbols-sharp {
  color: #dadada;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arkaplan {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 120px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1920px;
  background-color: #121212;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.anasayfa {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  margin-top: 90px;
  width: 1105px;
  height: 1720px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.blok {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.lock {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #252525;
}

.kurallar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

em {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-style: normal;
  /* Removes italics */
  text-decoration: 1.5px underline #dadada;
  /* Makes underline */
}

p {
  font-family: 'Skyline Beach NBP', sans-serif;
  color: #dadada;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}

.baslik {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #dadada;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  font-family: 'Skyline Beach NBP', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #dadada;
  text-decoration: 1.5px underline #3c3c3c;
  z-index: 22;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: none!important;
  outline: none!important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="arkaplan">
      <div class="anasayfa">
        <div class="blok">
          <img class="lock" src="goruntuler/img.png">
          <p class="baslik">thehamam nedir?</p>
          <a id="kurallar" href="https://thehamam.com/kurallar" target="_blank"><span>kurallarımız</span></a>
          <p>eğer 3 kelime ile özetleyecek olursak "özgür sosyal ağ" olacaktır. genişçe tanımlarsak günümüz platformlarındaki kısıtlamaların bulunmadığı isteyen kişilerin anonim kalabileceği yegane ağ. unutmayın, thehamam verilenizi canı gibi korur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blok">
          <img class="lock" href="/" src="goruntuler/pepe.png">
          <p class="baslik">peki bu ağda ne yapılıyor?</p>
          <p>onlarca konudan birini seçip gönderi oluşturabilir, dosya yükleyebilir, ruh halinizi yansıtacak wojağınızı seçebilir ve gönderilere cevap verebilirsiniz. kurallarımız baskıcı değildir. fikirlerinizi özgürce ifade edebilirsiniz.</p>
        </div>
        <p sid="son" bu sayfanın sonu olsa gerek!></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```